# Enable migrations with N-Tier Repository pattern Visual studio project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Using an N-tier application .
There is Repository Layer,Service Layer and Presentation Layer projects.
Only Repository Layer has reference to entity framework .
Only Presentation Layer(web.config) has configuration string.
I have used `IDbContextFactory` and Dependency Injection to inject configuration

How to enable migrations It gives error

> Checking if the context targets an existing database...System.ArgumentException: The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.    at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)    at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)

As I mentioned the connection string(configuration) is injected from Presentation layer I am using Autofac for DI

Here is the Context Factory as used in repository layer

```
 public class MyContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
    {
        public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
        private readonly string _configuration;
        public MyContextFactory(string configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public MyContextFactory()
        {

        }
        public MyContext Create()
        {
            var dbcontext =new MyContext(_configuration, Logger);

            return dbcontext;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code? This error clearly indicates that you forgot to pass connection string.

Comment: The code is working , I have developed it without enabling migrations...As I mentioned the connection string is injected from Presentation layer I am using Autofac for DI

Answer (score 0):

The *make it work* answer is to add the *connection string* into the `app.config` of your repository project. (Just copy it from `web.config`)

When you point *migrations* to that project, I don't think it's smart enough to know where to look for the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

After much research( almost 2 days ) I got the solution :
Add following parameter less constructor to the DbContext class And also make the web project the start up project when ever working with migrations (ie commands such as enable-migration,add-migration in the PM console.)

```
 #region Needed For migrations
        private static string ConnectionStringForMigration()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        public MyContext()
            : base(MyContext.ConnectionStringForMigration())
        {

        } 
        #endregion
```